# Numpy calculate Min Max in random 2D or 1D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to get a sum of Min or Max value in each row. If the number on first index is bigger than 12, return the max number in the row, else return min number in the row. Note that in below given sample, it's a 4 x 3 2D array. However I want my code to work given any array size or shape.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[11, 12, 13],
                [14, 15, 16],
                [17, 15, 11],
                [12, 14, 15]])

i_max = np.amax(arr,axis=1)
i_min = np.amin(arr,axis=1)
print(i_max)
print(i_min)
```

So far I can only get to the Min or Max number in each row using `amax` and `amin`. What I'm lacking is to access first value  in each row and use if else statement to compare the size to 12. Can anyone give a hint.

The correct output for given sample should be `11 + 16 + 17 + 12 = 56`

Comment: By "any array shape", do you mean arrays higher than 2 dimensions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.where contains **3 inputs**.
The first one is your **condition** *[ False, True, True False ...]*
The **second** and **third** inputs, are *the possible values*.

Thus, if the condition is True, grep the value of the second input
otherwise, take the value of the third input.

```
np.where(arr[:,0] > 12, np.max(arr, axis=1), np.min(arr, axis=1))
```

return: `array([11, 16, 17, 12])`

and if you need the sum, just add sum :) :

```
np.where(arr[:,0] > 12, np.max(arr, axis=1), np.min(arr, axis=1)).sum()
```

return: `56`

another way to represent it is like:
`[xv if c else yv for c, xv, yv in zip(condition, x, y)]`

or just read the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html :)

Comment: Add `.sum()` after the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You can create a `mask` (whatever you desire, here is first element of each row greater than 12) and calculate your operation as below. This is easily extendable to multi-dimensional array by changing the axis in `min/max` and your desired `mask` condition:

```
mask=arr[:,0]>12
(arr.max(1)*mask + arr.min(1)*~mask).sum()
```

output:

```
56
```

---

**Comparison**:

```
def m1(arr):
  mask=arr[:,0]>12
  return (arr.max(1)*mask+arr.min(1)*~mask).sum()

#@Dieter's solution
def m2(arr):
  return np.where(arr[:,0] > 12, np.max(arr, axis=1), np.min(arr, axis=1)).sum()
 
in_ = [np.random.randint(100, size=(n,n)) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

**Runtime**: **m1** seems a tad faster, however, they converge to same performance in larger arrays.[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using `benchit` on a notebook? You might want to try out the new release `0.0.4`, which has a much better support for the same now. Here's a sample run - https://github.com/droyed/benchit/blob/master/docs/source/PlotDemo-NotebookEnv.ipynb . TL;dr : Use `benchit.set_environ('notebook')` before plotting.

Comment: @Divakar I am using your `benchit`, thanks for the contribution :). However, I don't use notebooks, just the terminal. Is the new release an upgrade for notebooks only?

Comment: Well it's a general improvement across all backends. The specs are not showing up in this plot, so I thought its a notebook run. In your case, it might be a non-interactive backend, assuming you are not intentionally hiding the specs. Try out the new release if and when you can and let me know if it shows up, assuming you do want them to show up. Note : You still gotta use `benchit.set_environ('notebook')` for non-interactive backends.

Comment: @Divakar Will upgrade then. Thank you again. I deliberately remove the specs from the graph as it is not useful info for the post.

Comment: Well specs is an important part for a benchmarking, when someone else might want to test out the same benchmarking setup at their end. Like lot of times, someone with larger memory can go further on dataset sizes. So, those NumPy optimizations only show up at that far end. Regardless of the specs issue, the general improvements with the new release should be helpful.